# Smart cards for encrypting/decrypting using AES or TripleDES or RSA?

Tags: security, encryption, smartcards

I need some hardware device (not as big as a Thales or Atalla HSM), something like a smart card (with USB preferably) to **encrypt and decrypt** small texts (around 64 bytes). I didn't find much in a google search, only one called [YubiHSM](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubihsm/) ($500) which performs AES encryption / decryption, any other devices (*hopefully cheaper*)?

**PKCS#11** is desired, but I'd like to see different options. Also, I need the device to **generate and store a few keys** (right now I just need to generate and store one master key). The application that would interact with this device runs on **Linux**.

Comment: please clarify more clearly what you expect this smart card / HSM to do (AES? 3DES? RSA? ECDH?). Please also clarify the required APIs (PKCS#11? Java API? Microsoft CSP?).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

### The [Feitian ePass2003](https://www.ftsafe.com/products/PKI/Standard/Specification)

(or some other token from their ePass line)

- It costs less than a YubiHSM - Feitian sells them at 70USD for five pieces + customs, taxes and shipping
- It supports RSA, AES and 3DES with card-stored keys
- It supports the Windows CSP and has a PKCS#11 library
- It claims support for Linux, Windows and OS X
- It's a USB form-factor, about as large as your average USB-stick
- As a bonus [it has a FIPS 140-2 Lvl 3 certification](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm#2204) and is the *only* token that you can freely purchase with this level of assurance